# javascript to match string start with " and end with "; and anything in between?

Tags: javascript, regex

know how to match one pattern using jaascipt:

```
var pattern = somePattern

    if (!pattern.test(email)) { //do something }
```

but what if I have to match string start with " and end with "; and  anything in between with a specific length(10) so if I have this:

```
"ww#="$==xx"; (acceptable)
"w#="$==xx"; (Not acceptable, the length is 9 between the " and the ";)
ww#="$==xx"; (Not acceptable), doesn't start with "
"ww#="$==xx" (Not acceptable), doesn't end with ";
```

How can I achieve this using js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.{10}` to match exactly 10 characters.

```
^".{10}";$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/26)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want a solution other than regex, then the following function can also test if the passed string matches your criteria or not..

```
function matchString(str){
    var result = "InCorrect";
    if(str.length != 13)
        result = "InCorrect";
    else{
        if(str[0] == '"' && str[str.length-1] == ';' && str[str.length-2] == '"')
            result = "Correct";
    }

    return result;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhs1gq9m/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=^".{10}";$)^".*";$
```

You can use postive lookahead to check the length.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oC9iD0/1